# Problems with Python Crawler

Tags: python, html

I'm new to python and I am trying to code a crawler, my issue is that I cannot get the `href` links I am targeting to display in the console. Any help is appreciated, see below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.rent.ie/houses-to-let/renting_dublin/page_'+ str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        special_divs = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'search_result_title_box'}) 
        for link in special_divs:
            gold = link.findAll('a')
            for link in gold:
                href = gold.get(link['href'])
                print(href)
        page += 1

trade_spider(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you've found that `search_result_title_box` class, I'd locate the links inside the elements with `search_result` class. The following code works for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def trade_spider(max_pages):
    """Docstring here."""

    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"}

        for page in range(1, max_pages):
            url = 'http://www.rent.ie/houses-to-let/renting_dublin/page_{page}'.format(page=page)
            response = session.get(url)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            for link in soup.select(".search_result h2 > a[href]"):
                print(link["href"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trade_spider(3)
```

Note the following improvements:

- we are using the [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to improve on performance (underlying TCP connection is reused) and to configure common things like HTTP headers
- we are using a real browser's `User-Agent` string
- we are [explicitly specifying `html.parser` as an underlying parser used by `BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use)
- `.search_result h2 > a[href]` is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to match the desired links in the search result headers. The `>` means a direct parent-child relationship.